# about measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

If A and B are disjoint subsets of real numbers, and one of them is measurable can we say
m*(A U B)=m*(A)+m*(B)?
I am unable to find counter example. I feel this is not true.

Comment: Does $m^*$ here denote (Lebesgue) outer measure?

Comment: yes m* is Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: The title of this question should be made more specific.  

Comment: I am voting to close as "off topic", because of the level.  (I know from your comment at your other question that when you asked this you weren't clear on the purpose of MO, and I won't repeat what was said there.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true.  If for example  A is measurable it is measurable in the sense of Caratheodory so that
For every set C we will have 
$m*(C) = m*(C\cap A) + m*(C \setminus A)$.

This with $C=A \cup B$  is your assertion